# Null space of a zero line-sum matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am interested in understanding the null space of a rectangular [zero line-sum](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/293024/properties-of-zero-line-sum-matrices) matrix $\mathbf A\in\mathbb R^{m\times n}$. I understand that $\mathbf A\mathbf e=\mathbf A^\top \mathbf {e'}=\mathbf 0$ by definition, where $\bf e$ and $\bf e'$ are vectors of all ones in appropriate dimensions.

I get that the subspace of $\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ spanned by $\bf e$ is in the null space. However, intuitively, there might be other vectors in $\mathbb R^n$ that must be included in the null space. What are they?

How does it get affected if $m>n$? What happens otherwise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general there is no reason to expect the null space of $A$ to contain anything other than the multiples of $\bf e$.  For example,

$$ \pmatrix{2 & -2\cr -1 & 1\cr -1 & 1\cr} $$
is a $3 \times 2$ zero-line-sum matrix with null space spanned by $\bf e$.

The matrix has rank at most $m-1$ and null space of dimension at least $n - m+1$, so if $n > m$ there are other vectors in the null space.  But there is no reason to expect any **particular** vector other than the span of $\bf e$.